# How to filter json data with multiple includes values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Includes method working for only one Value but i want to **filter multiple values with comma like this** "mahmoud, faizan" i'll get these value from user input

json Data

```
[{
    
    "text": "adnan hassan"
}, {
    
    "text": "adnan hassan mahmoud",
}, {
    
    "text": "adnan hassan faizan",
}]
```

Filter Function

```
const filterFunction = (a) => {
   if(includeKeyword)
     return a.text.includes("mahmoud")
    }
```

Filter Function with map render

```
postRes.filter(filterFunction).map((data, index) => (
```

Comment: array.some may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave you two return statements to choose from, depending on if you want to match **all parts** or **at least one part** out of what was typed in:

```
const filterFunction = (a) => {
   if(includeKeyword)
     const parts = userInput.split(",");
     // if you need the returned element to match *all* parts (AND)
     return parts.every(p => a.text.includes(p.trim());

     // if you need it to match *at least one* part (OR)
     return parts.some(p => a.text.includes(p.trim());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

for your senario you can customize the filter function to get a second parameter and use array.some:

```
const filterFunction = (a, searchArray) => {
  if (searchArray.some((v) => a.text.includes(v))) {
   return a;
    }
 };
const result = postRes.filter((item) => filterFunction(item, ["mahmoud", "faizan"]));

console.log("result ", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter function returns a boolean. You can set this boolean with a loop :

Example :

```js
const base = [{
    
    "text": "adnan hassan"
}, {
    
    "text": "adnan hassan mahmoud",
}, {
    
    "text": "adnan hassan faizan",
}]

function myFilter(base,query){
  const queries = query.split(",")
  return base.filter((a)=>{
    let doReturn = false;
    queries.forEach((q)=>{
      if(a.text.includes(q)){
        doReturn = true;
      }
    })
    return doReturn;
});
}

console.log(myFilter(base,"faizan,hector,mickey,mahmoud"))
```

Answer (score 1):

create a array from your search text with split(','):

```
const searchParams = searchText.split(',');
```

then filter your data array like this:

test is your data array searchParams is the list of search parameters:

```
test.filter(t => searchParams.some(v => t.text.includes(v)))
```

[here is a little example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-galileo-2v91hg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

if you like to solve by javascript methods, like many people pointed out

```
if (["mahmoud", "faizan"].some((v) => a.text.includes(v))) {
    return a;
  }
```

if you like regular expression, do this way

```
if(a.text.match(/(mahmoud|faizan)/)){
    return a
  }
```